# how can i get multiple values to display from a mapped api which has multiple images within the already looped array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, string, dictionary

im trying to loop through an API with images, which I will change to fruits to make it easier to read

```
let arr = [
  {src: "mango, banana"},
  {src: "melon"},
  {src: "apple"},
  {src: "pear"},
]
```

notice how **"apple, banana"** are together

if I map them `arr.map(e => e.src)` it comes out like

```
[ 'mango, banana', 'melon', 'apple', 'pear' ]
```

when I try to do a `arr.map(e => e.src.split(','))` then it gets separated but I cant still use it like this

```
[ [ 'mango', ' banana' ], [ 'melon' ], [ 'apple' ], [ 'pear' ] ]
```

how can I access or separate the first array to be single, I need it to render images for a react app, but some fields have multiple images like that which breaks the code.

the outcome that I want is to have them all separated into single string

```
[ 'mango', 'banana', 'melon', 'apple', 'pear']
```

i tried something like this

```
let pushed = arr.map(e => e.src)
console.log(pushed[0]);
// output: mango, banana
```

and I get to select those and I could split them and work with those, but that's too hard coded, I need it to be dynamic as I am getting over 4000 pictures and I cant be checking every single field to see which one I have to change

Comment: Please do two things, if you can: post your code, and replace the images of text with the text itself .

Comment: maaannn xd, i need to change this question, I think I did it wrong, sorry, ill edit it out again

Comment: You could flatten the array you produce with your second approach. Refer to [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close to a right solution. If you pass a `.flat` after the `.map` function, it'll flatten your array to one level like such

```js
arr.map(val=> val.src.split(",")).flat()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .reduce function to have result you would like to have.

```
arr.reduce((prev, current)=> [...prev, ...current.src.split(',')], []);
```